# Can not find a java.io.InputStream with the name [fileInputStream] in the invocation stack

Tags: parameters, action, inputstream

Can not find a java.io.InputStream with the name [fileInputStream] in the invocation stack. Check the  tag specified for this action.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear , by what I've understood , you are trying to search "FileInputStream" under "InputStream" both classes belong to "java.io" package.

You can search like this :[image]

Answer (score 0):

The fileInputStream variable should have getter and setter.